# HTML/PHP - How can I remember which page people leave of?

Tags: php, html, session, cookies, session-cookies

So I did the front-end work for an exhibition/products site.

There are multiple products listed on there, when the user clicks on the 'order' button it sends them to another ordering site (still on the same hosting but a **different platform, not in my control** and I did **not build it**). After they order their stuff on there and click 'save' it sends them back to the **homepage (main.php)** but how can I change it that they go back to the place they left of? I suppose this is being done by the **use of a cookie**? I don't really have any knowledge about that so I would greatly appreciate some pointers.

For example what it **now looks like.** When a user proceeds to order an item and click through the pages.

products.php → order-platform.php (not in my control) → main.php (homepage)

What it should **look like.**

products.php → order-platform.php (not in my control) → **products.php** (where they left of)

Comment: Normally in this sort of integration scenario the ordering platform would ask you to provide a redirect URL as part of the config / setup settings which define the integration. That way, their application knows where to send the user to after their part in the process is finished. So maybe check those settings. Work with the provider / consult their documentation it you're still stuck.

Comment: @ADyson I tried that but they told me that they need 'my help' in order to complete this without any actual info

Comment: Perhaps they want you to tell them which URL you want it to redirect it to? I don't know, I can't guess what they wanted. I can't read their minds any more than you can. Go back and ask them what specifically they need from you.

Comment: Yeah I asked them but they didnt reply yet hehe @ADyson Thanks for the replies!

Comment: You might use cookies or $_SESSION if the redirect URL is not working as you might expect.